# PHP Google Sheets API quick start problems

Tags: php, composer-php, google-sheets-api

I'm attempting to use the Google sheets API. I'm following their instructions exactly from this URL: https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/php

And of course the reason I'm posting here is because I'm getting a confusing error :)

The steps I'm taking are

Install Composer:

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

and I get a success message.

I then run: `php composer.phar require google/apiclient:1.*` like requested from google and I return.

```
php composer.phar require google/apiclient:1.*
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

The first time I ran it the `Nothing to install or update` line gave me a message about the google package installing as you would expect.

I then run `php quickstart.php` like directed with the code on the google link I included. I return the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Google_Service_Sheets' not found in /path/to/quickstart.php on line 12
```

Obviously Google Service Sheets is supposed to be included in Composer since Composer deals with package dependencies, considering I can't find it anywhere in my vendor package when I run a `grep 'Google_Service_Sheets' . -R` (other than in `quickstart.php` of course)

The other thing I noticed is that on line 7 of quickstart.php:

```
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-php-quickstart.json');
```

That hidden directory `~/.credentials` isn't found anywhere on my server. But I included the `client_secret.json` on line 6 in my working directory.

Comment: same here...too bad no one knows the answer for this, else they would help us poor beings..

Answer (score 0):

Folder .credentials is located in the user's home folder. For example on my Windows PC I've found it under C:\Users\.credentials

For Unix\Linux systems you can use `echo ~username` to get user's home dir.

Comment: I stated I had checked for the file originally when I posted this question. Thanks for your reply anyways :)